# Xamarin.UITest on Android: Dismiss keyboard with Entry.Completed

Tags: android, xamarin, keyboard, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I'm testing a Xamarin.Forms app with an `Entry` element. I'd like to enter some text and dismiss the keyboard raising the `Entry.Completed` event. On iOS this is working nicely with `IApp.PressEnter`. On Android, however, this only inserts another whitespace.

How can I dismiss the keyboard such that `Entry.Completed` is raised?

I could imagine [invoking a backdoor method](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/backdoors/) or [executing methods on the native views](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/cheatsheet/#Invoke_a_Method_on_an_AppResult_or_UI_Element), but I couldn't get it to work, yet. Do you know how to raise `Entry.Completed` programatically from within Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I found a solution and it's rather trivial.

While the `IApp` interface has no method that is dismissing the keyboard and raising `Entry.Completed` on Android, there is `AndroidApp.PressUserAction()` for the desired purpose. So we can write:

```
(app as iOSApp)?.PressEnter();
(app as AndroidApp)?.PressUserAction();
```